# Why Loading Images takes so much memory even though their sizes are 2KB

Tags: android, performance, memory-management, imageview, adobe-illustrator

I have 5-6 `PNG` images each 2kb in size, and when i load them to my `ImageView`'s, on `Android Monitor` it shows **12 MB** more added to allocated memory.
i don't know what other factors are there that takes so much memory.
while i see other applications that are using many images per screen, they have no issue with performance and image quality.
I have tried using `SVG`'s quality got better but performance dropped.

- Is there a recommended way to display images without quality drop and memory friendly?

Comment: "each 2kb in size" -- the size of the compressed image file (e.g., PNG) does not matter. What matters is the resolution of the image.